# Why do i get failed to initialize COM library?

Tags: c++, events, notifications, wmi, qt5

I am trying to test an msdn sample on WMI notification in c++ which is located here: [Example: Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a Qt5.2 project.Everything compiles just fine and runs well, But when I try to run the sample code, I get stuck at the very beginning!
I get the error:

> failed to initialize Com library

I\ve read somewhere that it seems `Qt` itself initializes the com objects, So there is no need to re initialize it.
In that case if i comment the initialization part i get `CoInitializeSecurity` failure error.!
What am i missing here?

Comment: If Qt initializes COM for you it is a defect in Qt. Qt cannot possibly know how to initialize COM for you, since it doesn't know which appartment your thread should be in. The sample code tries to initialize the thread to be in the multithreaded appartment. If that fails, apparently Qt initialized the thread for the single threaded appartment. *EDIT:* Please provide the error code as well.

Comment: Thanks, This is the error code i get : 
Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0xffffffff80010106
And this is my code for logging the error instead of cout!

ui->txtLog->setText( "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" +   QString::number( hres ,16));

Comment: Error code 0x80010106 translates to: *"Cannot change thread mode after it is set."* To run the sample code you will have to create a new thread and pray that Qt stops being a PITA.

Comment: tried using this:
    std::thread t(&frmProcess::WMIMethod2,this);
    t.join();
instead of simply calling WMIMethod2, which resulted in this :
http://i43.tinypic.com/289dlrr.jpg

Comment: I suppose that was the *pray that Qt stops being a PITA* part I hinted to above.

Comment: thanks alot, i'll see how can i get around this if possible.

Comment: debug. find out what causes the error message. it might be as simple as forgetting to call `CoInitialize`.

Comment: @Cheers The call to `CoInitializeEx` is failing. I have no clue how this could ever be attributed to *forgetting to call `CoInitialize`*. You are very special.

Comment: @IInspectable: re "You are very special", thanks! re failure to imagine, it's an ability that can be trained (to some extent). have a happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The multi-threaded apartment is intended for use by `non-GUI` threads.
>   Threads in multi-threaded apartments should not perform UI actions.
>   This is because UI threads require a message pump, and COM does not
>   pump messages for threads in a multi-threaded apartment.

Instead of a GUI application in qt, i tried a console based one and it worked.